# How to get a bigger mantissa in Python programming language?

Tags: python, chaos, mantissa

I'm trying to make an animation of Feigenbaum's chaos. I try to program 600 images where I dive into the chaos of the image and then make them animated with MakeAvi. I have an mpmath library from Python, but it still feels like the value of the 10 exponent mantissa is limited. I can't go beyond image 82, which is equivalent to 15 frames per second animation with only 82/15 = 6 second animation. How could I increase the magnitude of the floating point mantissa? I suspect the value of the mantissa is currently limited to about 300. So I'm trying to make an animation like this:

https://youtu.be/5cT0H4Xk7JE

Comment: Would [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) work?

Comment: No. I even Import mpmath. Here is my code: [link](https://petke.info/Feigenbaum.txt)

Comment: You haven't explained what happens at image 82. Does your program fail? I tried to look at your code, and I was curious why the number of decimal precision has to go up at every iteration, and how you are casting integer literals to `int`.

Finally, the `getcontext()` within the `decimal` module only pertains to operations relative to the `Decimal` data type, which you have never instantiated. I don't have much experience with the `mpmath` package, but I don't know well enough about its implementation to know whether you can mix and match `float` with `mpf` instances.

Comment: I do not get error message in Python, but the image starts to be same as backround color ie. yellow. In REBOL-language in same program I get error message:

** Math Error: Math or number overflow
** Where: do-body
** Near: x: x * ((1 - x) * k)
>>
An when I print the x I get:

>> print x
-8.04656270944002E+237
>>

Comment: I think the overflow you're encountering is not an issue with the mantissa, but with the exponent. I looked at the decimal Python package, and you can adjust the exponent to be at most 10^18 - 1. The default max exponent (`Emax`) for decimal was 999999. Large values of `prec` would cause the decimal module to run out of memory at some point.